# img on mobile devices and desktop (responsive design)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, image, desktop

slideshow imgs are scaling correctly on mobile (responsive) however I don't want them to shrink when i resize my window on the desktop

---

```
.slideshow-wrapper{
      width:100%;
      max-width:980px; //this is the original width of image
}
#slideshow{
 clear:both;
 z-index:-5;
 width:100%;
}
#slideshow img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

---

```
 jQuery.each(slideArray, function(index,value) {  $("<img src='img/slides/"+value+"'   
 width='980' height='450'>").appendTo("#slideshow");
 });
```

---

```
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
 <div id="slideshow"> &nbsp; </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Part of the point of responsive design is that it doesn't matter if it's mobile or not; a small viewport is a small viewport, and should be accounted for. A user with a very small PC display should be catered to  just as a mobile user should be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lightweight solution to detect mobile users: https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

You can use this to load two different CSS-files. One with resposive images and one with static images.
Hope that helps.